# git: recover untracked files after git stash - git stash apply

Tags: git, centos7, restore, git-stash

After

```
sudo git stash
sudo git stash apply stash@{1}
```

untracked files which were not stashed were deleted.

Is there a way to restore them? I'm using Centos 7.

Tried to list these files in git somewhere
`git rev-list -g stash | xargs -n1 git ls-tree -r | sort -u | grep conf`
but cannot see what I'm searching.

Comment: i dont think you can recover information you havent stored..

Comment: may be it is possible not by git tools but using some linux recovering instruments

Comment: something like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/recover-deleted-files-on-linux)? i havent tried but seems worth to try. afaik, the chances getting something back intact after you mess (write stuff) into the disk is pretty slim.

Comment: Thank you so much, Bagus! Useful link. Actually I already restored system - did git pull again and found old config files. Seems like it works, huh. Really appreciate your help, thank you. I was in such a panic that any word is useful.
Will copy the whole repo folder for any changes next time..

Answer (score 0):

Restored system - did git pull again and found old config files.
Will copy the whole repo folder for any changes next time..